# How to detect "alt+p" in a modern and cross-platform manner, using KeyboardEvent.key?

Tags: javascript

When working on some JavaScript code that handles keyboard shortcuts, I noticed that [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and we should be using [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

I rewrote my code. It's much clearer now. However I got some reports from users on Mac OS that it was no longer working. I don't have a Mac, but after doing some debugging on Browserstack, I found that when you press alt+p in Chrome on Mac OS, `event.key` is "π" rather than "p" as it is on other OSes.

I could hardcode that in, but it's ugly and also would be highly annoying because alt+p is not my only keyboard shortcut.

So I'm wondering, how am I supposed to handle this situation? How do I detect alt+p, or alt + some other key, and have it work reliably across platforms? Well, I know `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` can do it, but it's deprecated...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be it. Thanks, I am blind!

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be helpful, but have you tried checking`KeyboardEvent.altKey` for Mac users
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey